# Within a dict, how to cut a out special value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Hi I want ask how to effectively cut out the value `share_link`

My code

```
j = {
    u'items': [{u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'a'},
               {u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'b'},
               {u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'c'},]
}
```

My first try is `print "Value: %s" %  j.get('items')[0]['share_link']`

It works, but it is too slow, e.g. if `share_link` has 20 times:

```
print "Value: %s" %  j.get('items')[0]['share_link']
print "Value: %s" %  j.get('items')[1]['share_link']
...
print "Value: %s" %  j.get('items')[19]['share_link']
```

May I ask, is there a more effective way to cut out this value?

Something like this:

```
b = j.findall(‘share_link’)

# print every share_link value
```

Comment: Would `share_link` be nested at any depth?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`for` loop statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) to iterate items (dictionaries in `j['items']`)

```
>>> j = {u'items': [
...     {u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'a'},
...     {u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'b'},
...     {u'annotations': [], u'share_link': u'c'},
... ]}
>>>
>>> for item in j['items']:  # Iterate each item
...     print('Value: %s' % item['share_link'])
...
Value: a
Value: b
Value: c
```

Answer (score 2):

*One-line* solution using `map` function to get a formatted output:

```
print '\n'.join(map(lambda i: "Value: %s" % i['share_link'], j['items']))
```

The output:

```
Value: a
Value: b
Value: c
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below will search for a given `key` in an `obj` at any depth.

(Note: Python2 below)

```
>>> def search(obj, key):
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         for item in obj:
...             for res in search(item, key):
...                 yield res
...     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
...         for k, v in obj.items():
...             if key == k:
...                 yield v
...             for res in search(v, key):
...                 yield res
... 
>>> list(search(a, "share_link"))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```